# cookies are not site wide

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have an MVC website and I'm using cookies for amongst other thing to store a site theme. I have the following function to set cookies... this resides in _Layout.vbhtml which is the 'master page' for all my site.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires; + "path=/";
    }
```

Even though I have specified a root path my cookies don't always work site wide.

The cookies are set in one of two places... in _Layout.vbhtml I also have...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //Set User Theme Preferences
        //First check theme cookie and if null Or empty set to default values
        var $theme = getCookie('myTheme');

        if ($theme == "") {
            //theme cookie does Not exists Or has expired
            setCookie('myTheme', 'bootstrap', 90);
            $theme = "bootstrap";
        }

        if ($theme != "bootstrap") {
            //theme is not bootstrap so change css link
            $("#cssTheme").attr("href", ('@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")').replace("bootstrap", $theme));
        }
    })
```

And I also have this click function in Home/Index.vbhtml - only place where a user can change the theme.

```
$("button[data-theme]").click(function () {
            $theme = $(this).data("theme")
            setCookie('myTheme', $theme, 90);
            $("head link#cssTheme").attr("href", ('@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")').replace("bootstrap", $theme));
        });
```

So with all cookies cleared if a user launches the site they get the standard bootstrap theme. The site url at this point would be **http://domain.com/sitename/**

If the user changes the theme now the myTheme cookie is saved, the css link is changed and any other page that the user visits will be in the correctly chosen theme.

My problem is when the user returns to the home page which is the same index page but because of action links the URL is now **http://domain.com/sitename/Home/Index/** - if the user **changes the theme now**, the index page theme is changed but navigating to any other pages gives the previous theme. Returning back to the home page will give the latest chosen theme... It's as if there are now two cookies one site wide and one specifically for Home/Index

Not sure why this is happening?

For completeness this is my getCookie function which resides in _Layout.vbhtml

```
function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad... I have home links at the top and bottom of each page and thought all my links back home used

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", "Home")
```

On checking the links at the bottom of the page used...

```
 href="~/Home/Index"
```

Using the top links always kept the URL as http://domain.com/sitename/ while the bottom ones gave http://domain.com/sitename/Home/Index

Changing them all to Action Links or `href="~/"` fixed the problem... although I still don't know why this would be is the cookie path was set to / (root)